# Google Drive app on Nexus 7 doesn't allow offline editing

Tags: google-drive, offline, documents

Okay, so I have a problem. 
I have a Nexus 7 (rooted, unlocked bootloader, but no other changes to the system).
I have a few google documents (native gdoc format, I'm the owner) that I'd like to edit in my spare, off-the-net time.

The problem is, when I select 'make available offline' in the application, the document appears in the offline tab, and I can edit it as long as I'm connected to a network. When I disconnect, wham, offline documents are set into read-only mode, I can select text, but I can't do anything else (also, there's that blue-ish bar on the top with ios-like "all docs" button).

So, what's going on? I really need to be able to edit some documents when I don't have an internet access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, at this point, marking something available offline only allows you to read it offline when using a mobile device [(Source)](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/97jXeWqKNtk). However, you can edit and write files offline if you are using a computer or device running Chrome or Chrome OS. I'm sure at some point Google will allow editing offline, especially for tablets, but at this point, I am pretty sure that you can online view files offline. Sorry.

Comment: But I was able to edit offline documents some time ago, on my nexus 7! So why can't i do it now?

Comment: Are you sure you were offline? Every site I have looked at, and when I try in on my own Galaxy S3, I get that you can only view files offline, but cannot edit them on mobile.

Comment: ...Right, maybe I was online then, and I forgot about that little fact :( 
Sorry!

...Doesn't change the fact that it's absolutely stupid that I can't edit it offline.

Comment: No problem. Even if it wasn't what you wanted to hear, could you please upvote my answer and mark it as the answer? Thanks.

Comment: I've marked it as solved, but I can't upvote it for some reason :/

Comment: Good. I forgot you didn't have enough reputation to upvote. Glad I could help though. Maybe Google will add this feature soon.

Comment: I'm nearly certain that there was a time when I was able to edit documents offline if I had marked them as available offline. I believe this feature may have been rolled back at some point.